# Is it possible to have clang-format add a newline before comments in a struct declaration?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Consider the following source.

```
struct ThreadId {
    /// The storage where this thread's state is held.
    ThreadContext* context;
    /// Differentiates this Arachne thread from others that use the same
    /// context.
    uint32_t generation;
}
```

I'd like to add a newline before the line that includes the word `Differentiates`. It seems that if I add it manually, clang-format will not remove it, but if I don't add it , clang-format will not add it.

Is there an option in `clang-format 5.0` that adds this newline automatically?

Comment: I don't think there's such an option, unfortunately